# Just a letter in codenames allowed?

Tags: codenames

Before you get angry with the question, I know that the the rules say "You can't use your clue to talk about the letters in a word or its position on the table".

I was just curious on a move I made if it was illegal. There were only 4 words that starts with H. The tiles were all our words, so I gave the letter H as a clue. I thought this was a once in a blue moon opportunity. What was I did just plain illegal?

Comment: I am downvoting because you quote the rules that clearly answer the question; so it's not clear or explained where your uncertainty comes from or what answer you expect other than the rule you already quoted.

Comment: As you say, the body of the question clearly outlines an illegal clue and even helpfully quotes the rule it is breaking.  However the question in the title is still interesting.  For example I would not have a problem with the clue "B - 3" given with the intention of indicating "Hive", "Grade" and "Note".

Answer (score 4):

It seems you already know the answer and it is illegal because you are not allowed to talk about the letters in a word. The rules are very clear that the clues you give have to be about the meaning of the word and what you are asking about would be in violation of them.

https://czechgames.com/files/rules/codenames-rules-en.pdf

> Your clue must be about the meaning of the
> words.

> Letters and numbers are valid clues, as long
> as they refer to meanings.

> The number you say after your clue can't be
> used as a clue.

> You can't say any form of a visible word
> on the table.

> You can't say part of a compound word on the
> table.

> Same-sounding words with different
> meanings and different spellings are
> considered different words

> Words that are spelled the same are
> considered the same

Comment: Maybe you should bold the second point "Letters and numbers are valid clues..." to highlight that the answer to the question is yes, provided the rest of the rules are folllowed.